# Gmaps Api V3 on Facebox problem view

Tags: javascript, google-maps, facebox

I need to view a Gmap (api v3) on a Facebox. But it don't work correctly.
I have the same problem tell in this blog http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-facebox-google-maps/ but if I try the solution there is a errore : "GSize is not defined".

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

GSize is part of the V2 api. Looks like you are trying to use v2 code while loading the v3 api.

v3 uses `new google.maps.Size()`

the code you want to fix a v3 map after it is redered is

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
```

Comment: I have the same problem. But triggering the event doesn't help. When exactly should I trigger the event? After creating the google maps? Or after the facebox opens?

Comment: after the box opens and the map has been rendered, you can trigger the resize event to 'fix' the map.